# Javascript: console.log Javascript object

Tags: javascript

```
var friends = {};

friends.steve = {
    firstName : "Steve",
    lastName : "Jobs",
    number: "(206) 555-5555",
    address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052'] 
};

function list(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(key instanceof Object == true) {
        console.log(obj[key].join(", "));
        } else {
        console.log(obj[key]);
        }
   }
}
```

Hi, I wanted to loop object friends.steve and console.log each of it's property, till now every thing is working, but I wanted that when my code reaches address array of my friends.steve object, it should log this address array like "One Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA, 98052" instead of like array, can anybody please help me with that how to do it. thanks

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/UJTP8/?

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UJTP8/4/)

- You need to check the value = `obj[key]` in case of an array. `key instanceof Object` will always return false.
- Try using `isArray()` or `instancof Array` instead of `Object`.

---

```
var friends = {};

friends.steve = {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Jobs",
    number: "(206) 555-5555",
    address: ['One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052']
};
list(friends.steve);

function list(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {

        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {    //Or if(obj[key] instanceof Array) {

            console.log(obj[key].join(','));

        } else {

            console.log(obj[key]);

        }
    }
}
```

---

Result:

```
"Steve" 
"Jobs"
"(206) 555-5555"
"One Microsoft Way,Redmond,WA,98052"
```

Comment: naaa don;t count on `if (obj[key] instanceof Object) {` also new Date()  will return true

Comment: Why those `JSON.stringify()` calls?

Comment: good catch. Was unable to update my answer version for some reason. It was from the inital answer. Updated the fiddle though

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the value is an object. The key will always be a string.

```
if(obj[key] instanceof Object == true) {
```

Maybe also use `Array.isArray(obj[key])`.

Answer (score 0):

don't count on `if (obj[key] instanceof Object) {`

However - you can do this  :

```
   for(var key in obj) {
        if(key =='address') {
        console.log(obj[key].join(", "));
        } else {
        console.log(obj[key]);
        }
   }
```

So in your example :

```
for(var key in friends.steve ) {
        if(key =='address') {
        console.log(friends.steve[key].join(", "));
        } else {
        console.log(friends.steve[key]);
        }
   }
```

result :

```
Steve VM204:6
Jobs VM204:6
(206) 555-5555 VM204:6
One Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA, 98052
```